# Proposition 6.6 in Hartshorne II: Bijectivity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Proposition 6.6 in Hartshorne II seeks to show that $\operatorname{Cl} (X \times \mathbb A^1) \simeq \operatorname{Cl} X$ for $X$ Noetherian, integral, separated, and regular in codimension 1.

A point of codimension 1 in $X \times \mathbb A^1$ is called type I if its image $y$ under the projection to $X$ is codimension 1. We can see such an $x$ is the generic point of the fiber of $y$.

A point of codimension 1 in $X \times \mathbb A^1$ is called type II if its image is the generic point of $X$.

I understand on a technical level, thanks to other questions on this site, the first two paragraphs of the proof. However, when Hartshorne goes to show the map

$$\pi^* : \operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} (X \times \mathbb A^1)$$

given by $\sum n_i Y_i \mapsto \sum n_i \pi^{-1} Y_i$, where $\pi$ is the projection to $X$, I do not understand the following statements:

1. Injectivity: If $D = \operatorname{div} f \in \operatorname{div} X$, then $\pi^*D$ involves only prime divisors of type I. Why?
2. Injectivity: The above forces $f \in K$, the function field of $X$. Why? He gives the reasoning that otherwise $f = g/h$, with $g, h \in K[t]$, which I understand, but then claims that if both are not in $K$, the divisor of $f$ will involve some type II divisor. Why is this true?
3. Surjectivity: Why does it suffice to check that prime type II divisors are linearly equivalent to sums of prime type I divisors? Do we already know we are surjective on type I divisors?
4. Surjectivity: Why does localizing a type II prime divisor at the generic point give us a prime divisor in the spectrum of $K[t]$?
5. Assuming the above statement, we see this divisor corresponds to a principal prime $P = (f)$ in $K[t]$. I see that just fine. Hartshorne then claims the divisor of $f$ is $Z$ plus possibly some purely type I divisors. Why?

I get the sense I am not thinking about divisors in general correctly, and, more specifically, I am not truly understanding the definition and implementation of type I and II divisors.

Comment: It would be a good idea for you to include what type I and type II divisors are in the post in order to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Writing $D=\sum n_iD_i$ for $D_i$ prime, we have $\pi^*D=\sum n_i\pi^*D_i$. But $\pi^*D_i=\pi^{-1}(D_i)$, and $\pi(\pi^{-1}(D_i))=D_i$, hence the image of $D$ does not contain the generic point of $X$, and all the $\pi^{-1}D_i$ are divisors of type I.
2. If $f=g/h$ in lowest terms for $g,h\in K[t]$ so that at least one is in $K[t]\setminus K$, then the valuation of $f$ at a maximal ideal containing a zero of whichever $g,h$ is in $K[t]\setminus K$ is not zero. Such a maximal ideal is a point in the fiber of $X\times\Bbb A^1$ over the generic point of $X$, so the divisor of $f$ contains a type II divisor.
3. Yes, we already know we're surjective on type I divisors: if $D\subset X\times\Bbb A^1$ is a prime divisor of type 1, then $\pi(D)\subset X$ is a prime divisor which maps to $\pi^{-1}(\pi(D))=D$.
4. Your statement is not super clear, but the point is that if $D$ is a prime divisor of type II, then it must intersect the fiber of $X\times\Bbb A^1\to X$ over the generic point of $X$ by definition of a type II divisor. As this fiber is exactly $\operatorname{Spec} K[t]$ and the divisor cannot contain the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} K[t]$ (this is the generic point of $X\times\Bbb A^1$), we get a collection of closed points in $\operatorname{Spec} K[t]$. If we had multiple points in this, we'd have multiple irreducible components of our divisor, so there's only one point, and thus we get a prime divisor on $\operatorname{Spec} K[t]$. (Alternatively, any prime divisor on a scheme $X$ has a unique point with $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,p}=1$ and no points with $\dim = 0$.)
5. Take $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ and $f=xt$. Then the divisor associated to $f$ on $\Bbb A^1\times\Bbb A^1=\Bbb A^2$ is the union of the axes, which is a type one divisor plus a type two divisor. There are worse examples, but this is one very accessible one; conversely, you might be able to fix this most of the time. Digging in to the stuff required to make it just a type II divisor is more work than you need to do here because we already know we're surjective on type I divisors, and so we don't have to figure it out to finish the proof.

Part 5 could make an interesting problem to think about further (when can one guarantee the divisor associated to $f$ is just a type II divisor?), but it's not necessary to finish this proof.

Comment: I'll be reviewing this soon and may have questions, but it looks initially to be exactly what I'm looking for in an answer.

Comment: @KReiser Hi KReiser, I have the same problem and I am still confused with a few points. Could you elaborate on the second point here? Because I don't understand why $g$ necessarily have a zero and I don't understand what is that maximal ideal neither. My try for this problem is to observe that any polynomial in $K[t]$ is of the form $f/a$ where $f$ is in $A[t]$ and $a$ is a constant in $A$, then since $f$ is in $A[t]-A$, it is neither zero divisor nor a unit, so I can apply Krull's Hauptidealsatz to find some minimal prime ideal of $A[t]$ of height 1 that contain $f$.

Comment: But I am not sure if the intersection of these prime ideals with $A$ will be the zero ideal as we desired. Do you think this works?

Comment: @Xin You're making this harder than it needs to be. To keep your approach, just apply Krull's Hauptidealsatz to $(f)\subset K[t]$ - the condition that $f\in K[t]\setminus K$ is exactly that $f$ is a nonzero nonunit, so it's contained in a height one prime of $K[t]$. Such a prime of $K[t]$ maps to the generic point of $X$ under the projection, thus the divisor of $f$ contains a type II point.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you so much for the answer, I am still very confused because I don't understand what does this $K[t]$ represent. Is $\operatorname{Spec} K[t]$ an affine open subset of $X \times A^1$? If not, why does a prime ideal of height one of $K[t]$ matter?

Comment: @Xin $K[t]$ is the coordinate algebra of the fiber of $X\times\Bbb A^1$ over the generic point of $X$. This fiber is as a set all the codimension-one points of $X\times\Bbb A^1$ of type II plus the generic point of $X\times\Bbb A^1$.